# How to discriminate type and array of type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, how can I discriminate between a user defined type and an array of such type?

```
type SomeType = { foo: string; };

function doSomething(x: SomeType | SomeType[]) {
    // Is x an array?
}
```

When the argument is a primitive type or an array, it is straightforward with `typeof`, but this does not work with user defined types.

Comment: `Array.isArray`

Comment: The missing piece, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.isArray` :

```js
interface A { }

function someFunction(prop: A|A[]) {
    if (Array.isArray(prop)) {
        prop.length
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IL4ChcwCuICYwA9iMgM7kC2EAYsaRSABQAOU5nAXGgA%20qANoBdAJSZcyWcmAxk7VFChwAngDpg1FWvVcenCVIwy5F7r00AbCCADmYABbnZePEA)

Comment: Thank you! Is it the same isArray as in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray ?